# Why is numpy.multipy() so expensive in this specific case with very a large multidimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Working on an EM-Algorithm, I'm currently fiddling around with the following code sample (this is within a loop, so i would be just zero):

```
    XminusMu = np.subtract(X, mu[i])
    matmul = np.matmul(XminusMu[:,:,np.newaxis],  XminusMu[:,np.newaxis,:])
    nominator = np.multiply(alpha[i], matmul)
```

The arrays have the following shapes:

```
XminusMu.shape = (1512090, 25)
matmul.shape = (1512090, 25, 25)
alpha.shape = (2,)
```

The weird thing is that even though these are huge arrays, I do quite a lot operations with them before this with no problem and very fast runtimes (trying to avoid loops whenever possible). 
Also in the case above, the substract and matmul operations are quite fast (The matmul operation takes 3-5 seconds, but I guess this is still reasonable for 1.5 Million outer products on the CPU?). However, calculating `nominator` takes up to 30 seconds, with the taskmanager showing, that python uses up to 5GB of memory. 
If I set a breakpoint after the calculation of the nominator, I can't even really evaluate it in the Visual Studio watch window, because the evaluation breaks/doesn't finish. This is no problem for all the other big arrays before running this line (e.g. running `np.sum(XminusMu)` during debugging in the VS watch window takes a split second, but `np.sum(nominator)` results in evaluation error.

Now, the question is: Is this just unavoidable (since `matmul` and `nominator` are still 25 times bigger than `XminusMu`), or is something wrong with my implemenation - meaning is there a faster way to calculate these multiplications?